# FifoBuffer - apache common collections 4 replacements

Tags: java, fifo, apache-commons-collection

I want to upgrade to apache.commons.collections4, but some classes as `CircularFifoBuffer` and `UnboundedFifoBuffer` are dropped

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.CircularFifoBuffer;
```

What are the right replacements for such classes?

Found several  [suggestions](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLACTIVATION-134):

> hadJan Haderka
>
> Or perhaps there's yet another option:
>
> replace buffer with MinMaxPriorityQueue which on it's own is also not thread safe, but guava fortunately provides wrapper for thread safety in form of Queues.synchronizedQueue(Queue q) call. Since we use guava elsewhere already it should be ok to use the library instead of commons. Not sure about performance comparison of the two tho.
>
> Cedric Reichenbach
>
> it seems like Queues#synchronizedQueue is indeed the equivalent of BufferUtils#synchronizedBuffer, i.e. synchronizes every access to the contained queue/buffer. However, a more precise match in Guava for CircularFifoBuffer would probably be EvictingQueue, or, since the sync wrapper works for any Queue, even Java's own Apache's new CircularFifoQueue.

I didn't find answer in [mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-dev/202006.mbox/browser) or [release notes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/release_4_4.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answers in task [COLLECTIONS-432
Replace Buffer interface with java.util.Queue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-432)

> BoundedFifoBuffer is replaced with java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
>
> CircularFifoBuffer is replaced with
>   java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.
>
> PredicatedBuffer transfered into PredivatedBuffer
>
> PriorityBuffer is replaced with java.util.PriorityQueue
>
> SynchronizedBuffer is replaced with
>   java.util.concurrent.SynchronizedQueue
>
> BlockingBuffer is replaced with java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
>   (practical java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue or
>   java.util.concurrent.SynchronizedQueue)
>
> BoundedBuffer is replaced with java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
>
> TransformedBuffer transfered into TransformedQueue
>
> UnboundedFifoBuffer is replaced with
>   java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue